# M1 MacBook Air unable to install VS Code. "Unable to write program user data."

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, installation

[Picure of Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aldY.jpg)I am trying to install VS Code on my new Macbook Air M1. I get the error message on the photo attached.

"Unable to write program user data.

A system error occurred (EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/John/Library/Application Support/Code')

Please make sure the following directories are writeable:

~/Library/Application Support/Code
~/.vscode/extensions"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue. The location for the `tmp` directory can be changed with the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=my-runtime-dir ./VSCode-linux-x64/bin/code --user-data-dir my_dir
```